# How to dynamically specify screens in React Navigation based on contents of redux store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My navigator is:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const screens = {
  Home: Homecreen,
};
if (this.props.userStatus !== 'active') {
  screens.Upgrade = UpgradeScreen;
}

const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(screens);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { userStatus: state.user.status };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainDrawer);
```

I want to show the `UpgradeScreen` only if the user status is not active. In the code above, I get the error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.userStatus')
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: in the line `if (this.props.userStatus !== 'active')` what `this` are you referring to? that block doesn't seem to be a part of any method...

Comment: @IshitaSinha That's the problem. `this` just refers to the app. I don't how to to refer to a compponent in navigation.

Comment: You should wrap it in a component. Can you please check my answer and if you have further questions, please write me a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have access to `this.props.userStatus`, you should have a component. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const screens = {
  Home: Homecreen,
};

const MainDrawer = ({ userStatus }) => {
  if (userStatus !== 'active') {
    screens.Upgrade = UpgradeScreen;
  }

  const Navigator = createDrawerNavigator(screens);

  return <Navigator />
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { userStatus: state.user.status };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainDrawer);
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in MainDrawer (created by Connect(MainDrawer))`

Comment: Oops. Fixed it.

Comment: My `HomeScreen` is actually is a stack of screens. This has caused navigation within the stacks to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

As jordan pointed out, that solution works out. Here is my snippet.

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Second: {
    screen: SecondScreen
  }
});

const MyApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);

const myCustomComp = props => {
  const username = useSelector(state => state.AuthReducer.username);
  const FirstCase = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
  const SecondCase = createAppContainer(
    createDrawerNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen
      }
    })
  );
  return username === "berkelmass" ? <FirstCase /> : <SecondCase />;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  username: state.AuthReducer.username
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(myCustomComp);
```